Require property for deserialization, but not for serialization
I'm setting Required = Require.Always on a JsonProperty in my ContractResolver. How can I make that property required for deserialization, but not for serialization using the same ContractResolver?
EDIT 1: Two tests that describe the requirement.
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Shouldly;
using Xunit;

namespace Energy10.Tests
{
    public class SomeFineTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1() =>
            Should.NotThrow(() =>
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new B
                {
                    Property = null
                }));

        [Fact]
        public void Test2() =>
            Should.Throw<Exception>(() =>
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>("{ Property: null }"));

        [Fact]
        public void Test3() =>
            Should.Throw<Exception>(() =>
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>("{ }"));

        public class B
        {
            [JsonRequired]
            public string Property { get; set; }
        }
    }
}


Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing where [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)] is causing problems during serialization?  Is it specifically with serializing null values? Because as far as I know (I could be wrong about this) the logic to detect missing values only applies during deserialization, when a missing value in the JSON forces an error.

Because if your requirement boils down to Using the same contract resolver, how can I have a property with Required.AllowNull during serialization but Required.Always during serialization I can probably suggest a way to do that.  But it's not clear to me that is exactly what you need, which is why a [mcve] would help.  Thanks!

@dbc thank you for your comment. I've been away, but have now made an example. And your description of the requirement is exactly what I need, as I understand it now.
